# I have drawn these diagrams, but need help with broken circles around the right-hand bullet using tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools,amscd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item[]$\widehat{L_2}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
\widehat{K_3} & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head, bend left] \arrow[rr, no head, bend right] \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              & \bullet \arrow[rrrrdd, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rrdd, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[dd, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[lldd, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[lllldd, no head] \\
\widehat{S_5} &                                 &  &                               &  &                             &  &                               &  &                                 \\
              &                                 &  &                               &  & \bullet                     &  &                               &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}
\widehat{A_0} & \bullet \arrow[out=150,in=210,loop,no head]
\arrow[r, no head]&\bullet
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
\widehat{A_1} & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head, bend left] \arrow[rr, no head, bend right] &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet
\end{tikzcd}$

\item []$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              & \bullet \arrow[dd, no head] \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &         \\
\widehat{A_2} &                                                  &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \\
              & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head]                     &  &                             &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\item []$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              &                                                 & \bullet \arrow[rd, no head] &                             &  &         \\
\widehat{A_3} & \bullet \arrow[ru, no head] \arrow[rd, no head] &                             & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \\
              &                                                 & \bullet \arrow[ru, no head] &                             &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\item []$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] \arrow[dd, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &         \\
\widehat{A_4} &                                                 &  &                              &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \\
              & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head]                     &  & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head] &  &                             &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              &                                                 & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rd, no head] &                             &  &         \\
\widehat{A_5} & \bullet \arrow[ru, no head] \arrow[rd, no head] &                             &  &                             & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \\
              &                                                 & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[ru, no head] &                             &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] \arrow[dd, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &         \\
\widehat{A_6} &                                                 &  &                             &  &                              &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \\
              & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head]                     &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head] &  &                             &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              & \bullet \arrow[rd, no head] &                                                 & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \\
\widehat{D_4} &                             & \bullet \arrow[rd, no head] \arrow[ru, no head] &                             &  &         \\
              & \bullet \arrow[ru, no head] &                                                 & \bullet                     &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              & \bullet \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &                                                   &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \\
\widehat{D_5} &                              &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head] \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &         \\
              & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head] &  &                             &  &                                                   &  & \bullet                     &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              & \bullet \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &                             &  &                                                   &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \\
\widehat{D_6} &                              &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head] \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &         \\
              & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head] &  &                             &  &                             &  &                                                   &  & \bullet                     &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              & \bullet \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &                             &  &                             &  &                                                   &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \\
\widehat{D_7} &                              &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head] \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &         \\
              & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head] &  &                             &  &                             &  &                             &  &                                                   &  & \bullet                     &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              & \bullet \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &                             &  &                             &  &                             &  &                                                   &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \\
\widehat{D_8} &                              &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rr, no head] &  & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head] \arrow[rrd, no head] &  &                             &  &         \\
              & \bullet \arrow[rru, no head] &  &                             &  &                             &  &                             &  &                             &  &                                                   &  & \bullet                     &  &
\end{tikzcd}$


\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}
              &                            &                            & \bullet \arrow[d, no head] &                            &                            &         \\
              &                            &                            & \bullet \arrow[d, no head] &                            &                            &         \\
\widehat{E_6} & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \circ
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}
              &                            &                            &                            & \bullet \arrow[d, no head] &                            &                            &                            &       \\
\widehat{E_7} & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \circ
\end{tikzcd}$

\item[]$\begin{tikzcd}
              &                            &                            & \bullet \arrow[d, no head] &                            &                            &                            &                            &                            &       \\
\widehat{E_8} & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \bullet \arrow[r, no head] & \circ
\end{tikzcd}$


\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I draw the following diagrams, but do you help me write the open circles around the right-most bullet by using `tikz-cd`? and Can I make the `L_2` loop diagram using `tikz-cd`?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be to add

```
\tikzset{
  OpenCirc/.style={
    label={[inner sep=0,minimum size=10mm, circle, draw, densely dotted]center:{}}
    }
}
```

to the preamble, and add `|[OpenCirc]|` to the start of the cells where you want the bullet circled. E.g.

```
... & |[OpenCirc]| \bullet \arrow[llldd, no head]
```

By the way, if you want the lines to reach the bullets, then you could define

```
Bullet/.style={
  circle, fill, draw, inner sep=0, minimum size=4pt
  }
```

and use `|[Bullet]|` instead of `\bullet` in the cells. For a bullet with a circle, use `|[Bullet, OpenCirc]|`.

Regarding your other question, you could do

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [Bullet] (a) {};
 \draw (a)
     arc[start angle=0,end angle=360,radius=5mm]
     arc[start angle=0,end angle=360,radius=8mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with the `Bullet` style defined above.

Here is a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{
  OpenCirc/.style={
    label={[inner sep=0,minimum size=10mm, circle, draw, densely dotted]center:{}}
    },
  Bullet/.style={
    circle, fill, draw, inner sep=0, minimum size=4pt
    }
}
\begin{document}
$\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small,row sep=small]
              & |[Bullet]| \arrow[rrrrdd, no head] &  & |[Bullet]| \arrow[rrdd, no head] &  & |[Bullet]| \arrow[dd, no head] &  & |[Bullet]| \arrow[lldd, no head] &  & |[OpenCirc, Bullet]| \arrow[lllldd, no head] \\
\widehat{S_5} &                                    &  &                                  &  &                                &  &                                  &  &                                 \\
              &                                    &  &                                  &  & |[Bullet]|                     &  &                                  &  &
\end{tikzcd}$

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [Bullet] (a) {};
 \draw (a)
     arc[start angle=0,end angle=360,radius=5mm]
     arc[start angle=0,end angle=360,radius=8mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: so much thank you

Comment: @tuce You're welcome. I just fixed a couple of errors in my answer by the way.

Comment: When I applied |[Bullet]|, my diagrams were broken, so the lengths of the arrows differed, what could be the reason?

Comment: @tuce I realize that the dotted circle would do that, because the label node increases the size of the cell, and thus changes the layout. Don't think using `
|[Bullet]|` alone would cause anything like that, though I only tried the one diagram. You could try modifying the `OpenCirc` style to `  OpenCirc/.style={label={[inner sep=0,minimum size=10mm, circle, draw, overlay, densely dotted]center:{}} }` (added `overlay`), but it's too late in the evening for me to do any more, so if that's not enough it has to wait.

Comment: I would be glad if you could look

Comment: My best compliments. For me it is very hard.

Comment: @tuce The main reason that the diagrams become asymmetrical (they are so in your original code as well) as that the labels, e.g. `\widehat{A_3}` are part of the diagram. Because of that the height the row containing that label becomes taller than the other rows. With my suggested method for making the bullets the effect is exaggerated, because a standard node with a `\bullet` is higher than an empty node with the `Bullet` style I defined. You can just keep using `\bullet`, personally I think I'd move the labels outside, e.g. `\widehat{A_3} \quad \begin{tikzcd} ...`

Comment: thanks for the help I'll try it @Torbjorn T.